# How many independent parameters in $e^{c_1x}+e^{c_2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While studying differential equations my friend had this doubt.
We might say two but exchange of non equal values of these gives the same curve so infact they are not independent,  so how many independent parameters are there?

For example, In $ax^2+bx+c$ we have three parameters the values of which gives a unique curve for each triplet and differentiating the curve three times gives us three equations to be used to eliminate parameters and form a differential equation ( here the third equation itself Is the differential equation,  a degenerate case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that we may rewrite this expression as $$f(x)=e^{c_1x}+e^{c_2x}=e^{\left(\frac{c_1+c_2}{2}x\right)}\left[\exp\left(\frac{c_1-c_2}{2}x\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{c_1-c_2}{2}x\right)\right]=2 e^{c_+ x}\cosh c_-x$$ where $c_{\pm}:=\frac{1}{2}(c_1\pm c_2)$. Written in this form, we see that $f(x)$ has two separate parameters, but is insensitive to the sign of the latter since $\cosh x$ is an even function. Including values of $c_-<0$ will thus 'double-count' the parameter space, and so we limit ourselves to the two-dimensional subset $(c_{+},c_-)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+$. This amounts to $(c_1,c_2)$ taking values in the half of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $c_1\geq c_2$. (Figuratively, we have 'folded' the parameter space in half along the line $c_1=c_2$.)

Comment: you only included $c_1\in\mathbb R^+$, which means $c_1> c_2$ which is not always so,maybe because $\cosh x$ is even,what if $c_+=2,c_-=-1$ and $c_+=2,c_-=1$ they give same curve,

Comment: if I am understanding well you have merged these types of cases into one, so as avoid multiples? Disregard my previous comment